# Collect data from website button output form

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-services, quantitative-finance

How can I collect data what is shown at the webpage after a button is pressed?

http://www.etf.com/etfanalytics/etf-fund-flows-tool

If you enter dates in this website, and click submit, it will create a new page with table of top 10 ETF inflows.

I am a beginner is web services and programming, but I know python and general programming. Any pointer how to do this is appreciated.

I need the data shown after the button press for research. 
Once I am able to get the data for specific date range, I will program it to be able to grab daily or weekly data automatically everyday.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This page has two form inputs. View the page source to determine the input names, then use the [requests library to post the form](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

```
import requests
response = requests.post(
    "http://www.etf.com/etfanalytics/etf-fund-flows-tool", 
    data={"startDate[date]":"2017-05-01","endDate[date]":"2017-06-01"})
print(reponse.text)
```

Now you have the html as `response.text` and you need to parse it. I recommend [lmxl's html parser](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) to do so, the code will look something like this:

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
top_creations_symbol_list = tree.xpath('//xpath/to/creation/symbols')
top_redemptions_symbol_list = tree.xpath('//xpath/to/redemption/symbols')
```

You'll end up with your symbols in two lists.